# Memory leaks C++ vector of pointers

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a little problem, I am using `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` and I see a lot of memory leaks. I thought that the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
  delete vect[i];
vect.clear();
```

would delete all what I want, what am I doing wrong?

PS:

`vector<Osoba *> osoby;`

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you show, please post a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is that you assume this is where the problem lies, but I see no error here unless you're deleting an already deleted pointer, but that would not generate a memory leak, but rather a crash instead.

Comment: I noticed that I'm creating another vector `vector<Osoba*> vect = fromFile(fileInp);` should i delete it too?

Comment: Are you sure it's these `Osoba` objects that are leaking?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, no, i'm no sure but i'm creating one vector to take all data from file `vector<Osoba*> vect` and i transfer it through the sort and compare function where i create `vector<Osoba *> osoby;` maybe it is a problem

Comment: As long as you don't remove any pointers from any vector without deleting them you should have no problem. But as the others say, there's really not enough details to know anything. By the way, if you make a debug build, doesn't `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` report leaks with file names and line numbers of where the allocation happened?

Comment: That code will correctly free the objects pointed to by elements the vector.  Whether that frees the memory the objects were using depends on whether `class Osoba` is well-behaved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code as posted will correctly delete all objects from the vector. However, I am certain there are other paths in your code, which do not delete objects, but simply destroy the vector.

To make sure this doesn't happen, either put objects (rather than pointers) into the vector (usually preferred approach), or, if you need owning pointer semantics, use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (in this order of preference).

Answer (score 0):

Delete all vectors you have created using your code. When you use a vector to store pointers, you must delete all new objects you have created (One delete for one new). A simpler approach is to use reference counting like shared_ptr as suggested in an other answer...

Even if it might not be your case, your code is correct unless your vector contains pointers to arrays : in this case, you must replace with delete [] vect[i];

Regards